# Partial Functors in Categories

Tags: category-theory

Does there exist the notion of a *partial functor* in category theory (namely a functor *F* in category **C** that is not defined for all arrows in **C**)? If yes, could you provide a reference?

Comment: Google "partially defined functor". But usually this refers to the situation that the functor is defined on a selection of *objects*, resp. a *full* subcategory. What do you exactly want to know?

Comment: I checked before posting, but didn't find any solid reference. Could you give me a pointer?

Answer (score -1):

What you describe is equivalent to modifying the codomain $\mathbf D$ to $\mathbf D^+$, which adds exactly one morphism for each source and target. (If you do not want the excluded middle it's similar but more messy.) The composition of new arrows with old ones results in new arrows.
Or you may choose to do it the other way round, by simply considering a functor from a wide subcategory of $\mathbf C$.